# Struts. Записать в переменную класса значание

Tags: java, jsp, struts

Подскажите пожалуйста в следующем вопросе. Работаю со Struts2.

Есть Action который обрабатывает запросы.

```
public class ComputerAction extends ActionSupport {

    private List<CompBean> ComputerList; // Хранит список всех компьютеров
    private String id;// Запоминает ID текущего компьютера
    
    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
    
        HibernateComputerDao daoC = new HibernateComputerDao();
        ComputerList = daoC.loadAllComputer();
        
        return SUCCESS;
    }
           // get/set metgods
}
```

И также есть JSP страница,которая выводит список всех компьютеров

```
<s:iterator value="ComputerList"  status="status" >
    <tr>
            <td>
                <s:property value="id"/>
            </td>
            <s:form action="computer" method="POST">
            **<s:hidden name="id" value="#ComputerList.id" />**
                <s:submit method="deleteComputer" class="link" value="Удалить"></s:submit>          
            </s:form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </s:iterator>
```

`<s:hidden name="id" value="#ComputerList.id" />` в переменную id ,хочу положить значение `#ComputerList.id` ,но ничего не выходит. Подскажите что делать.

Comment: value="#ComputerList.CompBean.id"

Comment: К сожалению,получается следующее:
id = #ComputerList.CompBean.id.

Т.е не значение строки,а сама строка записывается...

Answer (score 1):

В спрятанное поле надо писать значение из итератора. Если итератор сделан на список объектов, которые имеют атрибут `id`, то можно смело заносить это значение непосредственно в поле `value`.

```
<s:hidden name="id" value="%{id}" />
```